# RShiny giving different output to what is expected

Tags: r, shiny

I have the following code which gives me an output as a table:

Code:

```
library(tidyverse)
################################
# Fixed variables
mtsSqrd = 10000
rent = 20 # per square foot
# Variables & Assumptions
# in mts squared
operatingExpensesPerc = 10
# general vacancy
vacancy = 0.10
purchasePrice = 1000000
capRate = 0.08
growthRateInc = 0.03
growthRateExp = 0.02

unleveragedCapRateTableFunction = function(purchasePrice, capRate){
  generalPotentialRev = mtsSqrd * rent
  generalVacancy = generalPotentialRev * vacancy
  effGrossRev = generalPotentialRev - generalVacancy
  operatingExpenses = mtsSqrd * operatingExpensesPerc
  netOpInc = effGrossRev - operatingExpenses
  T = 5
  generalPotentialRev_T = generalPotentialRev*(1 + growthRateInc)^(1:T)
  generalVacancy_T = generalPotentialRev_T * vacancy # we assume the vacancy rate is fixed over the years
  effGrossRev_T = generalPotentialRev_T - generalVacancy_T
  operatingExpenses_T = operatingExpenses*(1+growthRateExp)^(1:T)
  netOpInc_T = effGrossRev_T - operatingExpenses_T
  salePrice = netOpInc_T[T] / capRate
  cashFlowOperations = c(netOpInc, netOpInc_T)[1:T]
  cashFlowStreams = c(purchasePrice*-1, cashFlowOperations[1:T-1], cashFlowOperations[T] + salePrice)
  internalRateOfRetrun = jrvFinance::irr(cashFlowStreams)
  return(internalRateOfRetrun)
}

percDecreaseIncreaseFunction = function(x, perc = perc, decrease = TRUE){
  if(decrease == TRUE){
    out = x + (x * - perc)
  } else {
    out = x + (x * perc)
  }
  return(out)
}



unleveragedCapRates = expand_grid(
  propertyPrices = c(percDecreaseIncreaseFunction(purchasePrice, 0.10, FALSE),
                     percDecreaseIncreaseFunction(purchasePrice, 0.05, FALSE),
                     purchasePrice,
                     percDecreaseIncreaseFunction(purchasePrice, 0.05, TRUE),
                     percDecreaseIncreaseFunction(purchasePrice, 0.10, TRUE)), 
  capRates = c(
    percDecreaseIncreaseFunction(capRate, 0.10, FALSE),
    percDecreaseIncreaseFunction(capRate, 0.05, FALSE),
    capRate, 
    percDecreaseIncreaseFunction(capRate, 0.05, TRUE),
    percDecreaseIncreaseFunction(capRate, 0.10, TRUE)
  )) 


map2(
  .x = unleveragedCapRates$propertyPrices,
  .y = unleveragedCapRates$capRates,
  ~unleveragedCapRateTableFunction(purchasePrice = .x, capRate = .y)
) %>% 
  unlist() %>% 
  matrix(ncol = 5, byrow = FALSE) %>% 
  data.frame() %>% 
  set_names(unique(unleveragedCapRates$propertyPrices)) %>% 
  add_column(capRates = unique(unleveragedCapRates$capRates)) %>% 
  relocate(capRates, everything()) %>% 
  round(4)
```

Output:

```
 capRates 1100000 1050000 1000000 950000 900000
1    0.088  0.0697  0.0813  0.0936 0.1067 0.1208
2    0.084  0.0776  0.0892  0.1016 0.1148 0.1289
3    0.080  0.0860  0.0977  0.1101 0.1234 0.1376
4    0.076  0.0950  0.1068  0.1192 0.1326 0.1469
5    0.072  0.1047  0.1165  0.1290 0.1424 0.1568
```

However, when I try to include this function into a Shiny App I get a different result.

Shiny App:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)

################################
# Shiny edits
setBackgroundColor(
  color = "black",
  gradient = c("linear", "radial"),
  direction = c("bottom", "top", "right", "left"),
  shinydashboard = FALSE
)

################################
# Fixed variables
mtsSqrd = 10000
rent = 20 # per square foot
# Variables & Assumptions
# in mts squared
operatingExpensesPerc = 10
# general vacancy
vacancy = 0.10
purchasePrice = 1000000
capRate = 0.08
growthRateInc = 0.03
growthRateExp = 0.02

unleveragedCapRateTableFunction = function(purchasePrice, capRate){
  generalPotentialRev = mtsSqrd * rent
  generalVacancy = generalPotentialRev * vacancy
  effGrossRev = generalPotentialRev - generalVacancy
  operatingExpenses = mtsSqrd * operatingExpensesPerc
  netOpInc = effGrossRev - operatingExpenses
  T = 5
  generalPotentialRev_T = generalPotentialRev*(1 + growthRateInc)^(1:T)
  generalVacancy_T = generalPotentialRev_T * vacancy # we assume the vacancy rate is fixed over the years
  effGrossRev_T = generalPotentialRev_T - generalVacancy_T
  operatingExpenses_T = operatingExpenses*(1+growthRateExp)^(1:T)
  netOpInc_T = effGrossRev_T - operatingExpenses_T
  salePrice = netOpInc_T[T] / capRate
  cashFlowOperations = c(netOpInc, netOpInc_T)[1:T]
  cashFlowStreams = c(purchasePrice*-1, cashFlowOperations[1:T-1], cashFlowOperations[T] + salePrice)
  internalRateOfRetrun = jrvFinance::irr(cashFlowStreams)
  return(internalRateOfRetrun)
}
######################################################################
unleveragedCapRateTableFunction(purchasePrice = 1000000, capRate = 0.08)

percDecreaseIncreaseFunction = function(x, perc = perc, decrease = TRUE){
  if(decrease == TRUE){
    out = x + (x * - perc)
  } else {
    out = x + (x * perc)
  }
  return(out)
}

# Define UI for application that draws a histogram
ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$h2("Change shiny app background"),
  setBackgroundColor("white"),
  
  # Application title
  titlePanel("Internal Rate of Return Computations"),
  
  fluidRow(
    column(3,
           numericInput("purchasePrice", label = "Price?", value = 1000000, min = 1),
           numericInput("capRate", label = "Capital Expenditure?", value = 0.08, min = 0, max = 1, step = 0.01),
           actionButton("computeIRR", "Compute IRR!")
    ),
    column(9,
           dataTableOutput(("irrTable")),
           dataTableOutput(("irrInputsTable"))
           #textOutput({"irrTable"})
           )
  )
)

# Define server logic required to draw a histogram
server <- function(input, output) {
  unleveredInputs <- eventReactive(input$computeIRR, {
    expand_grid(
      propertyPrices = c(
        percDecreaseIncreaseFunction(x = input$purchasePrice, 0.10, FALSE),
        percDecreaseIncreaseFunction(input$purchasePrice, 0.05, FALSE),
        input$purchasePrice,
        percDecreaseIncreaseFunction(input$purchasePrice, 0.05, TRUE),
        percDecreaseIncreaseFunction(input$purchasePrice, 0.10, TRUE)
      ), 
      capRates = c(
        percDecreaseIncreaseFunction(input$capRate, 0.10, FALSE),
        percDecreaseIncreaseFunction(input$capRate, 0.05, FALSE),
        input$capRate, 
        percDecreaseIncreaseFunction(input$capRate, 0.05, TRUE),
        percDecreaseIncreaseFunction(input$capRate, 0.10, TRUE)
      )) %>% 
      data.frame()
  })
  
  # observeEvent(unleveredInputs(), {
  #   print(unleveredInputs())
  # })
  
  unleveredIRR <- eventReactive(unleveredInputs(), {
    req(unleveredInputs())
    map2(
      .x = unleveredInputs()$propertyPrices,
      .y = unleveredInputs()$capRates,
      ~unleveragedCapRateTableFunction(purchasePrice = .x, capRate = .y)
    ) %>%
      unlist() %>%
      matrix(ncol = 5, byrow = FALSE) %>%
      data.frame() %>% 
      set_names(unique(unleveredInputs()$propertyPrices)) %>%
      add_column(capRates = unique(unleveredInputs()$capRates)) %>%
      relocate(capRates, everything()) %>%
      round(4)
  })
  
  output$irrTable <- renderDataTable(unleveredIRR(), options = list(pageLength = 5))
  
  output$irrInputsTable <- renderDataTable(unleveredInputs(), options = list(pageLength = 25))
  # unleveredIRR <- eventReactive(input$computeIRR, {
  #   unleveragedCapRateTableFunction(purchasePrice = input$purchasePrice, capRate = input$capRate)
  # })
  #output$irrTable <- renderText(unleveredIRR())

}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Where am I going wrong in the Shiny App? It runs and computes a table after clicking the `COmpute IRR!` button. However, using the default values I don't get the same table...

Table from Shiny App:

```
capRates    1100000 1050000 1000000 950000  900000
    0.088   0.0812  0.0928  0.1052  0.1185  0.1327
    0.084   0.0892  0.1009  0.1134  0.1267  0.1409
    0.08    0.0977  0.1095  0.122   0.1354  0.1497
    0.076   0.1068  0.1187  0.1313  0.1447  0.1591
    0.072   0.1166  0.1285  0.1412  0.1547  0.1692
```

EDIT:

Output from Shiny:

[image]

[image]

EDIT2:

Added sessionInfo()

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.5.0 (2018-04-23)
Platform: x86_64-suse-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: openSUSE Leap 15.3

Matrix products: default
BLAS: /usr/lib64/R/lib/libRblas.so
LAPACK: /usr/lib64/R/lib/libRlapack.so

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=es_ES.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C               LC_TIME=ca_ES.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=ca_ES.UTF-8     LC_MONETARY=ca_ES.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=es_ES.UTF-8   
 [7] LC_PAPER=es_ES.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                  LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C             LC_MEASUREMENT=ca_ES.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
 [1] shinyWidgets_0.6.2 forcats_0.5.1      stringr_1.4.0      dplyr_1.0.9        purrr_0.3.4        readr_2.1.1        tidyr_1.2.0        tibble_3.1.7      
 [9] ggplot2_3.3.6      tidyverse_1.3.1    shiny_1.7.2       

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_1.0.8.3        lubridate_1.8.0     assertthat_0.2.1    digest_0.6.29       utf8_1.2.2          mime_0.12           R6_2.5.1            cellranger_1.1.0   
 [9] plyr_1.8.6          backports_1.4.0     reprex_2.0.1        httr_1.4.2          pillar_1.7.0        rlang_1.0.5         readxl_1.3.1        rstudioapi_0.13    
[17] jquerylib_0.1.4     FinCal_0.6.3        bit_4.0.4           RCurl_1.98-1.4      munsell_0.5.0       broom_0.7.10        compiler_3.5.0      httpuv_1.6.3       
[25] modelr_0.1.8        pkgconfig_2.0.3     htmltools_0.5.2     sourcetools_0.1.7   tidyselect_1.1.2    fansi_1.0.3         crayon_1.5.1        tzdb_0.2.0         
[33] dbplyr_2.1.1        withr_2.5.0         later_1.3.0         bitops_1.0-7        grid_3.5.0          jsonlite_1.7.2      xtable_1.8-4        gtable_0.3.0       
[41] lifecycle_1.0.1     DBI_1.1.2           jrvFinance_1.4.3    magrittr_2.0.3      scales_1.2.0        vroom_1.5.7         cli_3.3.0           stringi_1.7.6      
[49] cachem_1.0.6        reshape2_1.4.4      fs_1.5.2            promises_1.2.0.1    xml2_1.3.2          bslib_0.3.1         ellipsis_0.3.2      generics_0.1.2     
[57] vctrs_0.4.1         FinancialMath_0.1.1 tools_3.5.0         bit64_4.0.5         glue_1.6.2          hms_1.1.1           parallel_3.5.0      fastmap_1.1.0      
[65] colorspace_2.0-3    rvest_1.0.2         haven_2.4.3         sass_0.4.0
```

Comment: Sorry, my original post posted two of the same data frame. I edited the post now to show the actual results. What I see is that the columns are mixed. The first column in the second table under `1100000` corresponds to the `1050000` in the first table. Apart from that the results are different so my assumption is I am passing something incorrectly to Shiny and its only taken the "first values" it sees and using these to compute the other columns...

Comment: I added my `sessionInfo()`

Comment: I will update my R now.

Comment: I get the same output both ways, as shown by @akrun.

Comment: Thank you both. I upgraded R to `4.2.0` and re-ran the code and get the same results. Its most likely that there was a problem in my code on my side which gave me the inconsistent results. But, I have everything working now. Thanks again